# How to reference (and modify) a slice of a scipy sparse matrix?

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, scipy

I'm trying to get a reference to a column-wise slice of a scipy sparse matrix, and modify it. I tried the following but the slice seems to be returning a copy instead of a reference (as is the numpy behaviour), so the original matrix is not modified.

```
>>> import scipy.sparse as sp
>>> A=sp.csc_matrix((10, 100))
>>> B=A[:, 0:1]
>>> B[:,0]=1
>>> B
<10x1 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 10 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Column format>
>>> A
<10x100 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 0 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Column format>
```

Comment: `scipy.sparse` does not do `views`.  I think the only thing that allows in-place access is rows of the `lil` format.

Comment: Look at `csr.get_col` [source] to get idea of what's involved in referencing a column

Answer (score -1):

I think you need to change the **dtype** to **ndarray** first. Try this:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.sparse as sp
A=sp.csc_matrix((10, 100), dtype=np.int8).toarray()
B=A[:, 0:1]
B[:,0]=1
B
array([[1],
   [1],
   [1],
   [1],
   [1],
   [1],
   [1],
   [1],
   [1],
   [1]], dtype=int8)
```